# ErrorException + unlink + Resource temporarily unavailable + Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a newbie in Laravel World. I've downloaded a project from gitlab.com and tried several time to run that project in my laptop.

In that project I've 6 migration files:

- users_table
- password_resets
- posts_table
- comments_table
- profiles_table
- categories_table

When executing `php artisan db:seed` command I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\photoblog-master\photoblog-master>php artisan db:seed
Seeding: UserTableSeeder

[ErrorException]
unlink(C:\xampp\htdocs\photoblog-master\photoblog-master\public\uploads/user-picture\61224db90375756038856cd51e1c48a7.jpg): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Would you please tell me how can I solve this error?

Comment: I think the file is locked due to it being in use. `unset()` the resource handle?

Comment: can you share the gitlab link or just the content of `UserTableSeeder` ?

Comment: Yeap. You must show us code.

Comment: The UserTableSeeder code :

Comment: <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\User::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($user) {
            $user->profile()->save(factory(App\Profile::class)->make());
        });
    }
}

Comment: Please add the code to your question instead of as an comment. Totally unreadable

Answer (score 2):

Is the file `C:\xampp\htdocs\photoblog-master\photoblog-master\public\uploads/user-picture\61224db90375756038856cd51e1c48a7.jpg` in use?

I have a similar issue when I opened a file and tried to delete it without fclose it first.

Comment: What do you mean by "in use"? How can that be possible during running a migration

Comment: Not sure in your case, but mine is, I fopen, and didn't fclose before I delete it. For example, fopen a file, and fwrite the content, then you'll need to fclose the file to delete it.